# How do i get the response text from a php script?

Tags: javascript, php, fetch-api

I'm using the fetch API to send data to a PHP script, which in turn processes it and returns a message using the exit() function.
I can see this response when i open the developers tool, under the nextwork tab, but i dont know how to access this response in my javascript code.
here is my javascript code:

```
fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
    }).then(response => {
      if (response.status === 200) {
        console.log(this.responseText); //this is the property i'm not sure of
      }
    }).catch( (error) => {
      handleError("you are disconnected");
    });
```

and here is my php code:

```
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
$category = $_POST['category'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
if ($comment && $category && $id) {
exit("invalid");
} else ....
```

Comment: The variable `this.responseText` contains the response text that was sent by the server. You access it using that variable.

Comment: @Mike - are you sure? that looks like an XMLHttpRequest thing rather than a fetch thing :p

Comment: this.responsetext returns undefined :-(

Comment: that because fetch response has no `responseText` property - you're thinking of `XMLHttpRequest` - which is a completely different animal

Comment: @JaromandaX I assumed it was an XMLHttpRequest. Guess I was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the body of the response. It's a readable stream though so you'll need to handle the promise.

Example:

```
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData,
})
  .then(response => response.json()) // read the response stream as JSON
  .then(data => console.log('Here is your actual response body', data))
  ... whatever else you want to do here...
```

In the example above, the stream is being read as JSON. For your particular use case, the `text()` method may be more suitable.

Comment: `response.json()` ... or `response.text()` (and others like arrayBuffer, blob, formData) if the API doesn't return JSON (no indication that it does) - in fact, no indication at all of what the OP's API returns

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks :) Answering based on habits haha but you're absolutely right, there are a number of methods that can be used.

Comment: the text() method actually worked out fine, thanks!